# How to know if a term is divisible by 10

Tags: analysis

I have some difficulties to solve this easy problem, could someone help me?

Is $4^{1000}-6^{500}$ divisible by $10$?

Comment: FWIW, you can also just look at the [exact answer](http://pastebin.com/FBzdykfg) to find that it is in fact divisible by $10,000$.

Comment: @imallett How about $4^{10^{1000000}} - 6^{10^{50000000}}$? ;)

Comment: @Thomas: certainly!  By examining these numbers, both of which end in "$\cdots1,787,109,376$", it's simple to discover that your expression is _also_ divisible by $10,000$ (and indeed a great deal more)!

Comment: @imallett Yes, "both of which end in", which implies you don't *need* to compute the entire number to look at the last digits, which is what your first comment was implicitly suggesting (and why I gave the tongue in cheek reply of submitting unimaginably large numbers to force you to consider only the last digits :p)

Comment: @Thomas . . . clearly.  And for the same reason, I answered tongue in cheek.¶  The larger point here is that for certain kinds of problems, the obvious approach should not be overlooked for a clever one.  Since the easiest thing works yet the OP hasn't said whether he cares about a general approach, I presented it as a comment in case he wants to amend the question.  Since it's been 5 hours, I think I'll post it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 42):

Your expression can be written as $16^{500}-6^{500}$. Recall that $a^n-b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 20):

HINT: What is the right-most digit of $4^{1000}$? What is the right-most digit of $6^{500}$? What does that tell you about the right-most digit of $4^{1000}-6^{500}$?

Answer (score 9):

we have $4^{1000}-6^{500}\equiv 6-6=0\equiv 0 \mod 10$

Answer (score 8):

We can see that $4^1 = 4$, $4^2 = 16$, $4^3 = 64$, etc. It starts out with 4 as the last digit, which when multiplied by 4 gives you a 6, which when multiplied by a 4 gives you a 4, setting up the pattern of 6 as the last digit for even powers. Therefore $4^{1000}$ has 6 as its last digit. Clearly all powers of 6 have 6 as their last digit because if you multiply something that ends with 6 by 6 the product will end with a 6 since $6\times6=36$. Since the last digits are both 6, when you subtract you get 0 as the last digit, which means the difference is divisible by both 5 and 2 and is therefore divisible by 10.

Answer (score 7):

$4^2 \equiv 6 \mod 10$

$\Rightarrow 4^{1000} \equiv 6^{500} \mod 10$

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear from your question whether you require a general method.  I've upvoted three of the other four answers here since they are all good.  In particular the [current best](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033992/33785) is the slickest trick and the [next](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033966/33785) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033973/33785) are good generalizations.

That said, as I mentioned in the comments, the obvious approach should not be overlooked for a needlessly clever one.  If you don't care about generality, then you can just evaluate the expression:

> 114813069527425452423283320117768198402231770208869520047764273682576626139237031385665948631650626991844596463898746277344711896086305533142593135616665318539129989145312280000688779148240044871428926990063486244662594025981424571409593728603035337632150388437182293551503447920102344948592677163033795451303978737969476432059651388725310756060866840299888538186292656743914465551536060049704715010157731117606858818025434780563119782817848700370999189150586174225945806076652256660690364965642083240783804920125367468611373661642590443113055089150622765944210552490560361847080855944387010578350080000

From here, it's pretty clear that it is divisible by $10$.  I hesitate to post this as an answer, since it's by far the dumbest--but I think it's important to remember that elegant solutions aren't always needed to solve simple problems.  Simple problems sometimes just have simple answers.